# delete customer and customer address manually from database in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have deleted the customer and customer address in `customer_entity`,`customer_address_entity`, but the customer details are still displaying in the Magento customer admin module.

When I click on all customers it's still displaying deleted customers data.

Comment: Run the indexing after this

Comment: can you please explain how to run indexing or just paste any reference link i will look into that

Answer (score 3):

By reindexing the magento we can solve above problem

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

for more information regarding index

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html#config-cli-subcommands-index-reindex